# ''More than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression'' postgres error

Tags: postgresql, request, geometry, postgis

I am trying to realize a postgres request :

```
select distinct nom_reg_12 
from region_15,repartition 
where st_intersects(region_15.geom,
                   (select geom 
                    from repartition 
                    where id_espece='Tetrarti'))=true;
```

but i get the following error :

> More than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

in the first time I tried this and it work fine :

```
select distinct nom_reg_12 
from region_15,repartition 
where st_intersects(region_15.geom,repartition.geom)=true;
```

and then I tried this a part to get the geometry I want :

```
select geom from repartition where id_espece='Tetrarti'
```

Comment: As per the message you have more than one row for the specified condition. Try to refine it...

Answer (score 0):

[Cross-posted](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247349/more-than-one-row-returned-by-a-subquery-used-as-an-expression-postgres-erro/247353#247353) on GIS StackExchange

You can move your condition outside of the subquery. ST_Intersects works on 1 row (for each geometry) at a time, so if you use a subquery it must also return just one row, and you probably have more than 1 'Tetrarti' row

```
select distinct nom_reg_12 
from region_15,repartition 
where id_espece='Tetrarti'
and st_intersects(region_15.geom,
                   repartition.geom)=true;
```

Answer (score 0):

First - you dont have condition for joining region15 and repartition in your SQL. You just add logical condition using subquery. it is nearly pure Cartesian. Your condition is like join all region_15 that intersects with any repartition with all repartition ;)

```
select nom_reg_12 
from region_15 r15,repartition r
where exists (select from repartition where id_espece='Tetrarti' and 
st_intersects(r15.geom,r.geom)=true); |
```

Remember to create spatial indexes for both columns

```
create index on region_15 using gist(geom);
create index on repartition using gist(geom);
```